# Work Backwards Through URL to Find the First Existing Folder

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

We have written an API that helps internal users upload and download from SharePoint Online via Excel and other tools. The code is all in C# and we have a 'Browser' UI that allows users to navigate to sites/folder/files by host etc.
We've had some feedback that if a user supplies an invalid folder request, can we work backwords until we find the first valid child folder of the Documents root.
So, as an example, a user provides the URL:
https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/client_XXXXXX_Description/Documents/AdditionalDocuments/CalculationMaterials/CalculationLogging/Job99/
Where both CalculationLogging and Job99 doesn't exist. What I need to do is, starting at Job99, work backwards each level until I find a valid folder, i.e. https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/client_XXXXXX_Description/Documents/AdditionalDocuments/CalculationMaterials/
BUT if its get as far back as Documents, then stop, and tell user they have provided an invalid path.
Here's my code though it feels a bit 'clunky'!

```
                // Define new object
            var gc = new GraphClient();
            // Check to see if the item exists
            var exists = await gc.CheckRemoteItemExistsAsync(model.Url);
            // Based on the results of the request
            switch (exists)
            {
                // The path is a valid file
                case "file":
                    // Store the actual filename from the path
                    model.FileName = model.Url.Substring(model.Url.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                    // remove the filename from the URL (as we don't use it)
                    model.Url = model.Url.Substring(0, model.Url.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                    break;
                // The path is a valid folder
                case "folder":
                    // Append a trailing / if not present
                    if (!model.Url.EndsWith("/")) model.Url += "/";
                    break;
                case null:
                    // Store the first parent folder as we know the existing child doesn't exist
                    var subFolder = model.Url.Substring(0, model.Url.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                    var folderLoops = subFolder.Split('/').Length;
                    // ** Where the path starts with http, deduct 2 from the length **
                    if (subFolder.Split('/')[0].StartsWith("http"))
                    {
                        folderLoops -= 2;
                    }
                    // loop through each folder until you find one that is valid
                    for (var i = folderLoops; i > 1; i--)
                    {
                        // If the parent folder is Documents
                        if (subFolder.Split('/')[i] == "Documents")
                        {
                            // Tell user path is invalid
                            MessageBox.Show(
                                string.Format(Resources.PathDoesNotExistsWarningMessage, $"{model.Url}"),
                                Resources.PathDoesNotExistsWarningMessageCaption,
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                            // exit the loop
                            break;
                        }

                        // Check to see if the item exists
                        exists = await gc.CheckRemoteItemExistsAsync(subFolder);
                        // Based on the results of the request
                        switch (exists)
                        {
                            // The path is a valid file
                            case "file":
                            case "folder":
                                break;
                            case null:
                                // Get the parent folder including the trailing /
                                subFolder = subFolder.Substring(0,
                                    subFolder.Substring(0, subFolder.Length - 1).LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                                continue;
                        }
                    }

                    break;
            }
```

The ** comment (line 4) is to explain I'm deducting 2 as when the path starts with https://, the split function will return https as item 0, and an empty string as item 1.
FYI The function CheckRemoteItemExistsAsync is using Graph API to check whether the path contains a valid DriveItem or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
            string input = "example.sharepoint.com/sites/client_XXXXXX_Description/Documents/AdditionalDocuments/CalculationMaterials/CalculationLogging/Job99";
            string[] splitURL = input.Split(new char[] {'/'});
            for(int i = splitURL.Length; i > 0; i--)
            {
                string[] URL = splitURL.Take(i).ToArray();
                Console.WriteLine("https://" + string.Join("/",URL));
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```